# Miller-Rabin won't work: problem with the base and the exponent

Tags: c, cryptography

I'm using strong known bases {2, 7, 61} to solve Miller-Rabin. Assume I take a = 2 in this piece of code and n = 5 to test its primality. The factorization of n-1, so 4, is 2*2*1 so my m is 1.
If I test 2^1 = x mod 5, I of course get 2, which will make my Miller-Rabin test fail even if 5 is prime.

```
while(m > 0) {
        if(m%2 == 0) {
            pow *= a*a;
            pow %= n;
            m -= 2;
        }

        else {
            pow *= a;
            pow %= n;
            m -= 1;
        }
    }

    if(miller_rabin_single_base(pow, n) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

...
```

The method I call at the end just checks if pow%n = 1 or n-1.

I can't understand if I misunderstood Miller-Rabin algorithm, or if there's some problem in the code. The code works with some primes only.

I'm also a C neophyte so I apologise if the error was just given by a bad coding.

Update:

declaration of the the single_base method:

```
int miller_rabin_single_base(int16 a, int16 n) {
    if(a%n == n-1 || a%n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

declaration of m and pow:

```
int16 nmu = n-1;
int16 m;
int16 k = 0;
while((nmu/2)%2 == 0) {
    k++;
    nmu = nmu/2;
}

m = nmu/2;
k++;

int16 pow = 1;
```

int16 is an unsigned short, I'm using it to test.

The n is an unsigned short number chosen by anyone who can run the code.

If I test for n = 5, 13 or 29 I get it is not prime, but If I test 7, 11 or 31 I get it's prime:

```
./p_test miller 17
composite number

./p_test miller 23
prime number
```

Comment: What are the definitions and/or declarations of `m`, `pow`, `n`?  What is the declaration of `miller_rabin_single_base()` function? How is the check `pow%n = 1 or n-1` written? Can you create a reproducible example, an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I added more infos, I hope they will help.

Comment: `typedef unsigend short int16` ? Why don't you `#include <stdint.h>` and use standard `uint16_t` ? Why don't you use just `int` ? Still, how is in the first snipped `a` defined? How is in the third snipped `n` defined? It would be good to have an mcve, I don't know how to merge all 3 code snippets into one program. We need an example, which others can copy and post on theirs compilers and run - try to create a simple compilable program `int main() { int a = 2, n = 5; ... your code ... }` and post it.

Comment: because I have a .h with all the other functions to call listed, and I typedef it in there.

Comment: Also Miller-Rabin test says the number is _probably_ prime. The pseudocode is even on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test). I guess the `a` number in your code is the random number between [2, n - 2] right?  Also I think if your `miller_rabin_single_base` returns 0 your function should ` continue WitnessLoop` as in pseudocode on wiki, not return from it, but I can only guess.

Comment: The problem is not that. The a are picked one by one by a for (there are just 3 a {2, 7, 61}, since they are the strong bases till a very large number I'll never reach). You can test Miller-Rabin by just finding the m and using it as exponent of the a,then modulo n(extended Fermat Little Theorem).The problem is that somehow this method doesn't always work for me. If the program would have said "8 is prime" I wouldn't mind since it's like a "8 is probably prime" but if the test says "5 is composite" then I'm sure it's totally wrong, since it means 5 has factors (which is false since it's prime)

Comment: the n is given as input, it's the only thing needed for the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've left out half of M-R. Given witness a=2 and n=5 with n-1=4 decomposed to 2<sup>2</sup>·1 you need to:

- compute a<sup>1</sup> mod n = 2 and compare to 1 and n-1 (-1 mod n); if equal to either this witness would say prime and you advance to the next witness, but it is not, and you had more than one factor of 2 in n-1, so keep going
- compute a<sup>1·2</sup> mod n = 4 and compare to n-1 (only, *not* 1); it is equal, so this witness says prime; in general you would advance to the next witness (or if no more declare n probably prime). If it were not equal, since you have reached k-1=1 factors of 2, you declare n composite and stop, but for n-1 values containing more factors of 2 you would iterate this step multiple times.

In this case, your other witnessess are unnecessary; 7 mod 5 = 2 so it produces exactly the same result, and 61 mod 5 = 1 and 1 as a witness says *every* number is prime, which is useless. For a more realistic (larger) n, they would be useful.

Note computing a<sup>m</sup>, a<sup>m·2</sup>, a<sup>m·2·2</sup>, a<sup>m·2·2·2</sup>, etc all mod n can be done more efficiently by first computing x = a<sup>m</sup> mod n then repeatedly computing x = x<sup>2</sup> mod n .

See [example in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Computational_complexity) (although they use different variable names).

Comment: Thank you, I was just coming here to say I've solved my issue but you gave a perfect explanation, in my code I did not compute the right thing at the beginning, that was the problem, I did not execute the for loop (that was present but that was skipped due to my exclusive if statement).